# Smallest C++ Program that will compile

Tags: c++

What is the smallest C++ program that will compile without any error?

Functionality is not important.

Comment: That is `int main(){}` , though I am certian this question will be downvoted/closed

Comment: Very simple:

    main();

this is the smallest program that compiles under Digital mars

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık: but that doesn't make it either valid C++ or a complete C++ program.

Comment: But user1.5M didnt ask for a complete program ^^

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık: Yes, he said (my emphasis): "What is the smallest C++ **program** that will compile without any error." I used the epithet "complete" only for emphasis.

Comment: "Functionality is not important." he said. My english is bad i think i accepted this as uncomplete :D

Comment: @closevoters: as you could see at the time you voted, this question has *a single, correct answer*. in other words, what you were saying with your votes, was already refuted by the information available to you when you voted. please do comment and *explain* why you still chose to vote in an opinion that at that time you had to know was in direct conflict with reality?

Comment: main; is the shortest C program: http://llbit.se/?p=1744

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that this is it

```
int main(){}
```

Comment: That won't compile. You must return am int value.

Comment: @MihaiTodor: No, `main`'s implicit return value is `0`.

Comment: There is some redundant whitespace between `)` and `{`.

Comment: @CharlesBailey don't be pedantic :P

Comment: @Xeo Indeed... Another language quirk that I hope I won't get to see in production code. Ever.

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: I was just highlighting an area for improvement.

Comment: @MihaiTodor: Why not? It is a commonly used feature. It's often relied on in programs that don't need to return a value and avoids otherwise undefined behavior.

Comment: You can simplify to just "main;"  http://llbit.se/?p=1744

Answer (score 12):

The following should be the shortest:

```
int main(){}
```

Note that omitting the return value without invoking undefined behaviour is possible only with `main()`.

Comment: Note that whether it indeed compiles *and links* without error depends on the toolchain. In particular, Microsoft's toolchain will by default not link it for the most common kind of Windows executable, a "GUI subsystem" executable. For that, one must use the not well-documented linker option `/entry:mainCRTStartup`.

Comment: The OP asked about compilation only, not linking.  Regardless, C++ requires `main()` to be declared with external linkage, so if Microsoft's linker can't process such a simple translation unit without throwing an error, then I suspect it's either not operating in a standards-compliant mode, or else the C++ standard permits linkers to impose additional restrictions on translation units (in which case _no one_ can provide a program which is guaranteed to link on any conforming toolchain).

Comment: Let me first address a simple error in your answer. The last paragraph that the return value can be omitted for `main`, is incorrect. If there is a `return`, then it must specify a return value (since the function is declared with one), and conversely, if you *meant* that a `return` can only be omitted without UB for `main`, well, it must be omitted for `noreturn` functions. The OP's wording commonly means compilation + linking, and that's the only interpretation that makes sense. Microsoft's linker (and their compiler) is *non-standard* by default.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, the C++ standard is quite clear that `main()` _must_ be defined as returning `int` but, uniquely, does _not_ require a `return` statement: "If control reaches the end of `main` without encountering a `return` statement, the effect is that of executing `return 0;`."  This quote is taken verbatim from §3.6.1 ¶5 of ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E); IIRC the wording in the 2011 standard is identical.  Except when using the new standard's `noreturn` attribute, no other function declared as returning a value may omit the `return` statement; `main()` is entirely special in this respect.

Comment: Right, except for the "no other function declared as returning a value may omit the return statement;". That's still incorrect.

Comment: -1 because "note that omitting the return value without invoking undefined behaviour is possible only with main()." is incorrect under both the literal and the very friendly forgiving interpretation, and the OP has refused to fix it.

Comment: I respectfully submit that I cannot have "refused" to fix the answer, since no one asked me to.  In response to your comment I happily clarified that it refers to functions returning a value.  If anyone else found the original wording to be imprecise then I humbly offer my apologies.

Comment: you're still refusing to fix it. it's not "imprecise". it's plain wrong.

Comment: @Alf: Can you provide constructive input as to what wording will make the statement correct, while maintaining the original point that flowing off the end of `main()` is well-defined behavior (equivalent to `return 0`), and flowing off the end of a value-returning function is undefined behavior (equivalent to `return` with no value).

Answer (score 6):

This will compile, but not link. ;)

```
~/blargh
16:48:24 $ cat t.cpp


~/blargh
16:50:21 $ clang++ -c t.cpp 
~/blargh
16:50:28 $
```

Comment: but it isn't a complete program so isn't (technically) a valid answer to the question. "A program shall contain a global function called `main`..."

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Hmm, true if you insist on the "program" part of the question.. oh well, it's a joke answer anyways.

Comment: And still, an empty file won the [1994 Obfuscated C contest](http://www.ioccc.org/years.html#1994_smr) for the smallest self replicating program. The file contains nothing, and trying to compile and run it also produces nothing.

Comment: This might well be a complete program in a `freestanding environment`.

Comment: This can link fwiw.  `g++ -Wl,--defsym=_start=_exit -Wl,--undefined=_exit -nostartfiles -static -o blargh t.cpp`  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14970087/839436